# Intuit.Ipp.Exception.IdsError while retrieving customers

Tags: vb.net, intuit-partner-platform

I have a web application using Intuit API V3 written in vb.net. My application has been working flawlessly while using QuickBooks desktop data. I began testing QuickBooks Online data today. The first time I logged in with my QuickBooks Online user it retrieved the customer list. Subsequent tries to retrieve the customer list fail.

The error message I receive is: 
"Fault Exception of type: SystemFault has been generated."
Inner Exception:
System.Collections.Generic.ICollection(Of Intuit.Ipp.Exception.IdsError)

```
     Dim customerList As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of Customer)

            '* create service
            Dim service As DataService = ValidateService(aPage)

            '* create a customer object
            Dim customerObject As Customer = New Customer()

            If aBool = True Then
                customerObject.CompanyName = ""
                '* get the customers
                customerList = service.FindAll(customerObject, 1, 500)
            Else
```

It fails on the line "customerList = service.FindAll(customerObject, 1, 500)"

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please enable logging and post the request/response: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0150_ipp_.net_devkit_3.0/logging

Comment: Thanks Peter, the log is too large to post here, can I email it to you or is there a way to attach it to this thread?

Comment: Derrick, Can you try to call Findall with 100 max results? See if it still gives error.  customerList = service.FindAll(customerObject, 1, 100)

Comment: Please try PasteBin.com or gist.github.com for posting the request/response

Comment: @peter
Trace log is located here:
http://pastebin.com/5JXzGz6v

Comment: @nimisha
I tried to make the max result smaller to no avail. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I see in your trace logs that you are getting the response from the service. In the linked shared by Pete above, there is way in which you can log request and response xmls. Can you enable that in your code and share the logs for request and response?

Comment: @nimishashrivastava
I added the specified lines to my webconfig file. I'm getting messages now.
Could not find schema information for the element 'intuit'.
Could not find schema information for the element 'ipp'.
And so on.
I have everything in the correct places in the webconfig file.
Any suggestions on what I'm missing?

Comment: Did you add the config section?  https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0150_ipp_.net_devkit_3.0/logging#Step_1:_Enable_Custom_Configuration

Comment: <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="intuit">
      <section name="ipp" type="Intuit.Ipp.Utility.IppConfigurationSection, Intuit.Ipp.Utility" allowDefinition="Everywhere" allowLocation="true"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

Comment: Add the above section too.

Comment: I copied the example when I first coded it. The configSections is there and the logger throws 6 messages no matter where I put it. It's like the project isn't seeing the intuit sectionGroup. Here are the summarized messages. "Could not find schema information for the elements 'requestLog', 'logger', 'ipp', and 'intuit'." "Could not find schema information for the attributes 'requestResponseLoggingDirectory', 'enableRequestResponseLogging'."

Comment: Did you add this in code- using Intuit.Ipp.Core; using Intuit.Ipp.Diagnostics; using Intuit.Ipp.Utility;

Comment: What pages specifically do those need to be in? I have them in Default.aspx. This may be a separate issue but now I get a different error in the Trace log. ???????????????????????? [*WARNING*]: ????????????????????????
08:34:00.8655 PM Failed while trying to send wake-up request to "https://localhost:2323/Default.aspx" due to "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.".

Comment: I was still unable to get the xml logging to work. Through messing with the web.config file I ended up making the application not work at all. I removed all the logging stuff from my web.config file, now the application works just fine both with QBO user data and QBD user data. I'm totally stumped as to why I couldn't make the xml log work but the application now works so I'm moving on. Thanks for all the support.

Comment: Hi Derrick, You will have to make the log work else you will stumble upon major issue with no way out. Going forward you can post your questions on the Live community https://intuitpartnerplatform.lc.intuit.com where other developers can help you out too

Comment: Thanks for all the useful information and the link to the Live community. I was unaware Intuit had created another forum for us to post on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through trial and error and stepping through my project for a couple days I figured out that my application was not storing the appToken properly so it kept coming back as an empty string. When the service was called it didn't have the correct credentials to successfully make the call. I was able to fix the issue with the appToken storage and the application is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim oauthValidator As New OAuthRequestValidator(oCommon.AccessToken,oCommon.AccessTokenSecret, oCommon.ConsumerKey, oCommon.ConsumerSecret)
context = New ServiceContext(oCommon.RealmId, oCommon.IPPDataSourceType, oauthValidator)
commonService = New DataService(context)
Dim qbCustomer As New Customer
Dim qbCustomers As New List(Of Customer)
qbCustomers = commonService.FindAll(qbCustomer).ToList
```

See if the above code works

Comment: The code is the correct way to make the call. I moved the code for creating the DataService into a function to make the call easier. I posted my resolution to the original issue. Thanks for the time on this @nimishashrivastava