# Intuit API V3 customerQuery object not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net, intuit-partner-platform

I'm writing an application using Intuit's API V3 written in vb.net. I'm trying to do a customerQuery on a customer using the Customer.DisplayName. I think I have the query set up but I'm missing something because I keep getting an object reference error.
Here is the code doing the query:

```
     '* create service context
            Dim context As ServiceContext = New ServiceContext(oAuthData.realmId, oAuthData.dataSource, oAuthValidator)            

            Dim list As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Customer)

            Dim customerQueryService As New Intuit.Ipp.QueryFilter.QueryService(Of Customer)(context)

            Dim selectBy As Intuit.Ipp.LinqExtender.Ast.Expression = New Intuit.Ipp.LinqExtender.Ast.SelectExpression(aCustomer.DisplayName)

            list = customerQueryService.Execute(selectBy, True, aCustomer.DisplayName)
```

I pass in a customer object with the DisplayName I want to query by. The context is getting created properly so that is not the problem. I get the object reference error when the execute query is called. What am I missing or what is wrong with this call?

Comment: Please paste your request xml here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @nimishashrivastava. I still have an open thread because I cannot get the xml logging working in my application. Here is the thread: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355303/intuit-ipp-exception-idserror-while-retrieving-customers). Can you tell me if my code looks correct without the xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is an example in C#-

```
QueryService<Account> accountQueryService2 = new QueryService<Account>(context);
Account account21 = accountQueryService2.ExecuteIdsQuery("Select * From Account where AccountType='" + AccountTypeEnum.AccountsReceivable+"'").FirstOrDefault<Account>();
```

Can you map it to VB syntax?

Comment: Thanks, I can convert it to VB. I will give it a try and see if I can get it to work. Thank you for all the help!